# How to make maven-surefire-plugin reuse created thread to execute all tests in all Maven modules

Tags: java, spring, maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

Maven-surefire-plugin has different settings to execute tests. If forkCount=1 and reuseForks=true, then surefire plugin creates one new JVM process to execute all tests in one Maven module. Is there an option to create one JVM process to execute ALL tests in ALL maven modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force Maven not to fork tests by setting the configuration parameter forkCount to 0.